# Apache redirect rule optimize

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, apache2

I'm trying to optimize my redirect

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^boycottplus\.org$
RewriteRule ^ https://boycottplus.org%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Part 1 is to redirect users that visit the .com site to the .org site

Part 2 is to redirect users that visit unsecure (http) to https

Is there a way to both redirect .com user to the secure .org site, and redirect http users on the .org site to the https site?  Both while keeping the {request_uri} intact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use both conditions in one rule while applying OR logic instead of default AND:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^boycottplus\.org$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteRule ^ https://boycottplus.org%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks.  I still can not figure out why it works in chrome but in firefox it redirects to the index.php page

Comment: Try clearing browser cache & restart -- it is possible Firefox still remembers old redirect from your previous experiments.

Comment: thanks.. got it figured out, had to move the rule to the top of the .htaccess as some rules were in there for clean urls